# Creating a typescript definition file for a vue package (vue-datetime)

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am using Vue.js in combination with typescript. I would like to use the [vue-datetime package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-datetime) in my project. The package has no typescript definition file yet so I'm trying to create a minimal version.

I have added a `index.d.ts` file to the `node_modules/vue-datetime` folder:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

declare class Datetime extends Vue { }
declare class DatetimePopup extends Vue { }

export default Datetime;
export { Datetime, DatetimePopup };
```

In my Vue component I can now import and use the package like this (note that I am using the [vue-class-component package](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) so the syntax might look a bit different than you're used to).

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-datetimepicker v-model="someproperty" class="myclass"></v-datetimepicker>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

    import Vue from 'vue';
    import Component from 'vue-class-component';
    import { Datetime } from 'vue-datetime';

    import 'vue-datetime/dist/vue-datetime.css';

    Vue.component('v-datetimepicker', Datetime);

    @Component({
        components: { Datetime }
    })
    export default class MyComponent extends Vue {

    }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

This works, nice. The problem is that I don't want to save my `node_modules` folder to source control. Because of this I thought it would be a good idea to save the definition file to the same directory as my vue component (are there better options?).

I moved the `index.d.ts` file and renamed it to `datepicker.d.ts`. I also updated my vue component which now imports the datepicker like: `import { Datetime } from './datepicker'`. This will give me no compile errors, but opening the page will throw me the following Javascript error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './datepicker'`.

I've been unsuccesful looking for solutions to this error online. Any ideas on what I could try or what is going wrong?

Comment: if you don't want to save node_modules folder to source control then why don't you just add it to .gitignore?

Comment: Well I have that but when I save the declaration file to the node_modules folder the file won't be distributed to other developers (since its ingnored by the .gitignore). And the file is required else the application won't compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update

There has been a [typed definition file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/aa5c66c087896ff55568b76ae49f77321ba0123a/types/vue-datetime/index.d.ts) added for the `vue-datetime` package in the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) repository.

### Original answer

Alright I've got it working. I had to do a couple of things.

**1**. Rename the declaration file `datepicker.d.ts` to `MyComponent.d.ts`. '`MyComponent`' is the exact name of the Vue component in which I want to use the package. I'm not sure if it is necessary but I have the declaration file in the same folder as the component.

**2**. I changed the content of the declaration file to:

```
declare module 'vue-datetime' {
    import Vue from 'vue';
    class Datetime extends Vue { }
    class DatetimePopup extends Vue { }
    export { Datetime, DatetimePopup }
}
```

**3**. I changed the import line back from `import { Datetime } from './datepicker'` to `import { Datetime } from 'vue-datetime';`

Now it all compiles and I don't have any runtime errors.